# charCodeAt() working with some validations, but not some other validations

Tags: javascript, validation, character

I could have sworn I validated everything properly until my teacher decided to look for every single possible combination of characters and somehow doc me for 10 points. So I went in my code and try to fix the validation but, even though this is just like the example in his lecture outline, it decides to let a1 unwantingly pass the form. I double checked the ascii char code chart using this [link](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

and the 1 still keeps getting through.  this is my code section:

```
else if(f1.state.value.length != 2 || 
    !( (f1.state.value.charCodeAt(0)>=65 && f1.state.value.charCodeAt(0)<=90) ||
    (f1.state.value.charCodeAt(1)>=97 && f1.state.value.charCodeAt(1)<=122) ))
    {
        alert('Please enter a state in abreviated form');
        f1.state.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

why does the 1 keep getting through?

edit: also, i notice 1a works (or doesnt work), but not a1..

Answer (score 0):

interesting, i took the ! out and put it around each individual parenthesese to ! and it worked.. so it was returning true if one or the other was true... then !ing it.

so it should have been :

```
else if(f1.state.value.length != 2 || 
        ( !(f1.state.value.charCodeAt(0)>=65 && f1.state.value.charCodeAt(0)<=90) ||
        !(f1.state.value.charCodeAt(1)>=97 && f1.state.value.charCodeAt(1)<=122) ))
        {
            alert('Please enter a state in abreviated form');
            f1.state.focus();
            return false;
        }
```